# Why is getMessage() an unresolved reference in Kotlin with an Exception class?

Tags: kotlin

[Kotin documentation says](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html) that "All exception classes in Kotlin are descendants of the class Throwable. Every exception has a message, stack trace and an optional cause."

[The Java documentation for Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) shows a getMessage() method. But the [Kotlin documentation for Throwable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-throwable/index.html) does not have a getMessage(). So this code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
   try
   {
      println("args size: ${args.size}");
   }
   catch (e: Exception)
   {
      println(e.getMessage())
      System.exit(1)
   }
}
```

gives me this compile error:

```
test_exception.kt:12:17: error: unresolved reference: getMessage
      println(e.getMessage())
                ^
```

suggesting that I am using a Kotlin Exception class derived from a Kotlin Throwable class.

However, if I change getMessage() to toString() and add a throw:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
   try
   {
      println("args size: ${args.size}");
      throw Exception("something went wrong")
   }
   catch (e: Exception)
   {
      println(e.toString())
      System.exit(1)
   }
}
```

I get this message:

```
java.lang.Exception: something went wrong
```

Which seems to say that the Exception class is NOT a Kotlin Exception class - but the java version which has a getMessage() method and I shouldn't get a compile error when I try to use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no other `Throwable` except for `java.lang.Throwable`. This class is used both by Java and by Kotlin programs.

The fact that `Throwable` has an entry in the Kotlin documentation suggests that this is a special compiler "alias". That means that for all intents and purposes it is a Kotlin class, instances of which are represented by `java.lang.Throwable`. Black magic.

TL;DR:

The equivalent of `e.getMessage()` in Kotlin is `e.message`, which is described in the docs as `open val message: String?`.

Since `Throwable` is not used directly from Java, but mapped to Kotlin, you cannot use the Java notation `e.getMessage()` for the property. Here is more about mapped types: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types